# drawing $\sqrt[3]{2}$

Tags: geometry, roots

I know that drawing cubic root of "2" ($\sqrt[3]{2}$) is not possible with just a ruler and a compass. But is there a way or a tool to draw this? I mean, a segment line with a length of $\sqrt[3]{2}$.

Comment: To have a tool that is able to trisect angles (a [Trisector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trisector) ) is enough. There are many ways, origami is a chance, for instance.

Comment: Indeed, you can construct $\sqrt[3]{2}$ with origami. See this wikipedia page : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematics_of_paper_folding#Doubling_the_cube

Comment: Using neusis i.e. A marked ruler....https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doubling_the_cube

Answer (score 0):

You can look at this [geogebra page](http://www.geogebra.org/m/337915)  and a link for some detailed explanations on [Origami vs straight edge and compass](http://origami.ousaan.com/library/conste.html).